# Why doesn't pandoc convert a plaintext file to PDF properly?

Tags: pdf, pandoc, converters, plaintext

***Commands tried:***

```
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=pdflatex 1.txt -o 1.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=lualatex 1.txt -o 2.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=xelatex 1.txt -o 3.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=latexmk 1.txt -o 4.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=tectonic 1.txt -o 5.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf 1.txt -o 6.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=weasyprint 1.txt -o 7.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=prince 1.txt -o 8.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=context 1.txt -o 9.pdf
pandoc -V 'fontfamily:Courier' --variable mainfont="Courier" --pdf-engine=pdfroff 1.txt -o 10.pdf
```

***Contents of 1.txt:***

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Left                                                                       Right
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum  1
whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever.    2
Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum  3
whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever.    4
Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever. Lorem ipsum whatever.              5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***Results:***

Out of all those allegedly supported "engines", only the first and third produce any PDF *at all* (the others just dump a bunch of nonsensical errors). And those two that do produce PDFs, produce horribly butchered ones:

1. "pdflatex" (the first command) entirely ignores the specified font, so it's completely useless.
2. "xelatex" (the third command) seems to be mostly using the right font, but seemingly deletes all the spaces between "Left" and "Right", morphs the "-"s into straight lines (that's *not* how that font looks...) and messes up the lines completely so that the numbers on the last columns are not aligned to the right, and has crammed the entire contents into the middle of the page instead of, as expected, near the top-left corner:

screenshot of the xelatex-produced PDF
[image: screenshot of the xelatex-produced PDF]

I have spent enormous amounts of times hunting for options and trying a million variations of the above commands, but it seems like this tool is fundamentally broken. I have no idea how others (apparently) use these tools, but they just don't work. It's impossible to convert a text file to PDF...

Comment: Why is Pandoc important for you? Have you looked at other libraries? Maybe using xelatex directly there are options you can use to get the output you want.

Comment: @Ryan Pandoc is not important at all to me. I have tried a million different ways, including GhostScript, and nothing manages to produce a proper PDF. I'm not joking when I say that I've spent years (on and off) trying to accomplish what I originally thought would be a 5-minute thing.

Comment: Every option you have listed so far is free of charge. I was able to generate a PDF that looked identical to your "1.txt" using the SDK that the company I work for developed. Are you open to commercial products? Are you only looking for pre-built command line tool?

Comment: @Ryan Unfortunately, I've lived a "free tier" life for as long as I can remember. Commercial/paid options were never an option to me for anything. As much as I would love to be able to throw money at problems, it's always just me wasting endless time eras hunting for that elusive imaginary tool which just doesn't exist for free in most cases. If you say, "you could have afforded the program by working the same amount of time you've spent being stuck on this problem", well, that goes for a lot of people, I'm sure, but sadly not for me. Long story. I just seem fundamentally unable to make money.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, existing command-line tool. I mean, what do you mean? As much as I like to imagine the perfect .exe for each of my problems, I don't really see the use of it in practice, since in order to produce such a thing, there's always money involved. Yet I don't have any. And this likely won't even bring in any money either...

Answer (score 8):

Pandoc is not broken; it is doing just what its documentation says it will do.  Pandoc treats your input file as Markdown with pandoc extensions (since you didn't specify a format). What you have here is a one-column simple table (since there is no break in the line of `----`s to indicate a column break).

If what you want is a rendering of this context as verbatim text in a PDF, you could use e.g. `enscript 1.txt --output=- | ps2pdf - > 1.pdf`.  If you want to do it using pandoc, then the easiest way is to put the content inside backtick fences so that it is treated as a markdown verbatim block.  One way to do this would be to modify your file, but you could also do it by creating a file `ticks.txt` containing just

````
```
````

and then run

```
pandoc ticks.txt 1.txt ticks.txt -o 1.pdf
```

Comment: That's a great workaround and I was happy to use it. I was compiling a bunch of files located in a directory ending all with .txt. So, I created a subdirectory "ticks" and created a file there named "ticks.txt", which contains the three ticks mentioned above. The problem with this workaround is that one will have a huge indentation for the text. There is a second workaround, using a two step conversion with wkhtmltopdf: ```pandoc ticks/ticks.txt *.txt ticks/ticks.txt -o out.html``` and ```wkhtmltopdf --encoding "utf-8" --minimum-font-size 20 out.html out.pdf```. This omits the indentation.